# Spring MVC - one message code works, another not and both are in the same file

Tags: java, spring, resourcebundle

I'm getting this error:

```
No message found under code 'DuplicateKey.user.username' for locale 'sk_SK'.
```

There are many questions on SO about messages files not loading properly, but my problem is that the file is loaded properly for sure. In my resource bundle I have two files:
messages.properties
messages_sk_SK.properties

The contents of messages_sk_SK.properties are:

```
Size.user.username=Meno musi mat 5 az 80 znakov.
DuplicateKey.user.username=Uzivatel s takym menom uz existuje.
```

The first message works fine. Code from my Entity:

```
@Size(min = 5, max = 80)
private String username;
```

The second error message is also for username. Here's the code from my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String signupPost(@Valid User user, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "signup";
    }

    user.setAuthority("user");
    user.setEnabled(true);

    try {
        userService.create(user);
    } catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
        result.rejectValue("username", "DuplicateKey.user.username");
        return "signup";
    }

    return "accountcreated";
}
```

DuplicateKeyException is thrown on duplicate username. How is this possible?

Comment: I assume your `messages.properties` file is selected for any other locale? Does that file include the same message, and does that one work correctly?

Comment: It has the same two error codes, but the messages are in English. I'm following one tutorial and first I had only messages.properties file and Size.user.username message in it. It worked fine. After I added the result.rejectValue(...) code and the second message in it, I was getting the same exception as now "No message found ...". So I created ...sk_SK file and put both messages in there, but in Slovak language. Now the Size.user.username is shown correctly in Slovak, but I'm getting the same error for DuplicateKey.user.username as before.

Comment: OK, so just to be completely clear `DuplicateKey.user.username` has never worked, for either locale?

Comment: Have you tried swapping that error key for `Size.user.username` in your `catch` block? That would tell you if the problem is in that specific message, or something else. Also, what happens if you add a third String to `result.rejectValue()`, as a default, does that get displayed?

Comment: If I try it with Size.user.username, it works. Adding the third argument (default message) also works.

Comment: Sounds to me like there's just something wrong with the key... I assume you've tried copying and pasting the key from the properties file into your code, to be completely sure that there's no strange character or typo in it? And maybe try with a completely different key, just like `a` or something?

Comment: Well I tried to completely change/remove the working one (Size.user.username) from the messages file and it seems like it's cached somewhere because it's still showing the same message that I had in the beginning. I'm deploying it from IDEA to local instance of JBoss Wildfly 9 and I tried redeploy/restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved it. According to the comments in the tutorial I'm following ([link](https://www.udemy.com/javaspring)), you have to do it another way in IntelliJ IDEA (they use Eclipse in the tutorial). I did move the messages files to resources folder, so now my dir structure is

```
src
  - main
    - java (sources)
    - resources (messages files)
    - webapp (WEB-INF, JSPs etc.)
```

and in my config xml:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="messages"/>
</bean>
```

You have to right-click on resources directory and Mark Directory As -> Resources Folder. The messages files should appear inside another node called Resource Bundle 'messages'. Now it works as it should. If it doesn't find a message in messages_sk_SK.properties, it tries to find it in messages.properties.

[image: dir structure]